# Flask-SQLAlchemy: How can I call db.create_all() and db.drop_all() without triggering database commits?

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a fairly standard Flask-SQLAlchemy setup connected to a PostgreSQL 9.4 database.

For testing purposes, I'd like to call `db.create_all()` within the scope of a database transaction, run my test, then call `db.drop_all()`--all without committing that database transaction. This is possible because PostgreSQL wraps DDL in transactions.

However, whenever I call `db.create_all()` or `db.drop_all()`, Flask-SQLAlchemy issues a `COMMIT` after *every* individual table is created. Similarly, it issues a `COMMIT` after each table is dropped.

I have `COMMIT_ON_TEARDOWN = True`, but AFAIK this should only matter for the final commit--it shouldn't cause the intermediate commits happening after each table.

How do I change this behavior so that the tables are created or dropped without automatically triggering database commits?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like sqlalchemy implements the create_all() with autocommit = True so probably there is no way to change this behavior.

The relevant code:
https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py#L199

https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/859379e2fcc4506d036700ba1eca4c0ae526a8ee/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py#L60

## Update:

My answer is correct for MySQL which does not support nested transactions ==> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/implicit-commit.html.
As @Jeff Widman mentioned in his answer there is a way to do it for PostgreSQL "by replacing the global session with one running in a nested transaction"

Comment: Thanks, this seems like it's the right answer. However, I ran across a blog post that seems to be working around this somehow because the DDL commits stay within the transaction--see the section "Transactional DDL":  http://koo.fi/blog/2015/10/22/flask-sqlalchemy-and-postgresql-unit-testing-with-transaction-savepoints/ I read and re-read that section, but can't seem to grasp it. Can you expand your answer to explain what he's doing to pull this off?

Answer (score 0):

I'm an sqlalchemy noob, but this seems to do the trick:

```
with contextlib.closing(engine.connect()) as con:
    trans = con.begin()
    database.metadata.create_all(bind=con)
    trans.commit()
```

Comment: This answers the opposite (and ill-premised) question: if `create_all` did _not_ trigger a commit, how would we artificially do so?